# Any way to avoid setting properties as attributes in old IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I am developing a [JavaScript library](http://www.petitjs.com) where I need to set various properties on DOM elements.

For example, a DOM element might have the property (a plain object) called 'states' set on it:

```
_('input').get('states')

/*        OUTPUT

    {
        hidden: true,
        anotherState: false,
        andAnotherOne: true,
    }

*/
```

In IE<9, the output will then look something like this (which I understand is just native legacy IE behavior):

```
<input type="text" value="some value" states="[object Object]">
```

Other properties will occasionally be set on DOM elements as well using the same method, and issues might pop up where there's a conflicting attribute and property set on the DOM element (IE<9 might tie up in that case).

Any way to avoid this, or is this just something you have to live with?

## Edit for clarification

To give an example in vanilla JavaScript, say you do this:

```
document.getElementById('foo').bar = 'foobar';
```

In any version of IE less than 9, the output in the DOM will appear like this:

```
<div id="foo" bar="foobar"></div>
```

In the very large majority of other browsers, this won't occur.

Now, if you do this:

```
document.getElementById('foo').bar = {
    a: 'b',
    c: 'd'
}
```

In any version of IE less than 9, you get:

```
<div id="foo" bar="[object Object]"></div>
```

Once again, this doesn't happen in most other browsers.

Comment: Not sure what you want...? Are you looking for `JSON.stringfy()`?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Looks like OP wants to prevent custom properties set to an element to reflect to attribute list of that element.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, Teemu is correct.  Please see the updated version of my question for more clarification.

Comment: @JoshBeam again, i'm confused. In your update, the `div` will not have a new attribute on the DOM element. Yes it will set a property, but it doesnt show of on the DOM : http://jsfiddle.net/4h422/1/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, yes, in IE7 it will show up on the DOM.

Comment: @JoshBeam Have you tried to remove the attribute immediately after property definition? Karl: In older IEs this works as Josh has described, you can't reproduce the issue with modern browsers.

Comment: @Teemu, I haven't tested removing it, but theoretically, removing the attribute in IE7 would also remove the property in IE7, wouldn't it? Since in IE7 properties on elements are like this: Element['someProperty'].  And in other browsers, properties on elements are like this: Element.prototype.someProperty.

Comment: @JoshBeam i wonder, if it work but the only *cons* is that in **IE** it show on the DOM, who would see that? Only Developer see the DOM but nobody develop in IE < 9. There is ,sometime, some sacrifices to do in life ;)

Comment: @JoshBeam I've only IE11 at hands, so I can't test a real case. Maybe you could set `document.expando=false` just before removing an attribute, then set it back to `true`?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought about your technique. You are effectively trying to modify a native object by appending a property for your data. This is not a good idea. It is effectively what the prototype library did to elements and that caused many bad problems and it why the library ultimately faded away.

The better approach is to create an object that wraps the element, which is what jQuery does. Now with that said you are trying to bind data to the element, probably for persistence. You might want to rethink that a bit. Maybe use the data- attributes or just persist the data in localStorage for example. I think you will find you have a much better solution to maintain, but will also be more performant.

Saying this as someone who tried and did what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: you can use data- in older versions, it of course would not validate in an HTML validator for that time frame. And I believe localStorage has been available since IE8.